# Apache and Tomcat 8 configure proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

I have a web application running in Tomcat 8. I can access this application by opening http://subdomain.domain.com:8080/MYAPP. 
Now I want to only enter http://subdomain.domain.com to open this application.

How do I have to configure my Apache 2 or Tomcat 8 to achieve this?

Comment: I solved my problem with the following answer:

http://serverfault.com/questions/397617/apache-mod-proxy-page-reload-and-sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer there for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26305876/1935128

But basically, you need `mod_proxy` and maybe `mod_proxy_connect` enabled on apache with a proper `virtualhost` configuration on apache side. And on Tomcat's side it may work without any modification but you should add `proxyName="subdomain.domain.com`, `proxyPort="80"` and `scheme="http"`

Tomcat connector :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
   <!-- This is the important part -->
   proxyName="subdomain.domain.com" proxyPort="80"/>
```

Apache virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerName          http://subdomain.mydomain.com

    # I think these two are optional, depending on the app your run on Tomcat
    #ProxyRequests          Off
    #ProxyPreserveHost      On

    ProxyPass               /       http://your.tomcat.server:8080/MYAPP/
    ProxyPassReverse        /       http://your.tomcat.server:8080/MYAPP/

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you so far, but I have one problem. The path of the tomcat 8 web application is like subdomain.domain:8080/MYAPP, so if I enter subdomain.domain.com in my browser I get redirected to the main site of the tomcat server, but I wanted to have the root subdomain.domain.com pointing to the original tomcat URL, without showing this ULR in the browser. Can you help me again?

Comment: My bad, did not read your question properly. You have to change both `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to add your path. Ex : `ProxyPass / http://your.tomcat.server:8080/MYAPP/` . I'm not sure about the last / though, Try with both `http://your.tomcat.server:8080/MYAPP/` and `http://your.tomcat.server:8080/MYAPP'` , tell me which one is right and I will edit my answer accorgingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is http://your.tomcat.server:8080/MYAPP/. Now it is working correctly.

Comment: Ahh...it is not working correct. In my application I have functions and they don't work anymore. Do I have to use something like ajp?

Comment: No AJP has nothing to do with that. It's likely a missing /. Did you try with `http://your.tomcat.server:8080/MYAPP/` ?

Comment: It is working, the redirect with proxy, but the interactive content on the page is not accessible. It was built with vaadin.

Comment: Ah ok I guess that you are calling `/MYAPP/some/ajax/call`. I don't know vaadin but there must be a configuration option somewhere to allow you to specify the proper url but I'm afraid it is beyond the scope of that question. If you can't figure out how to do this just ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63492/discussion-between-johnride-and-marcel-holl).